# Trouble on submitting a namespaced Account using its User ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to submit namespaced Account using an ActiveRecord association.

In the *router* I have

```
resources :users

namespace "users" do
  resources :accounts
end
```

In the *User model* I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account,
    :class_name  => "Users::Account"
end
```

In the *User controller* I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    ...
  end
end
```

In order to submit the User Account, in the *form view* I tryed to do like the following:

```
<%= form_for([:users, @user.account]}) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

but that doesn't work. So **what I have to do to make it to work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things look mixed up. You have view for users, but you are creating User::Account there?! In controller you didn't create that account. Perhaps:

```
@user = User.new :account => Users::Account.new
```

But pay attention that you either need to move your logic in Users::AccountController or if you want to create both User and it's account in the same view, than you use nested_forms for account and than you should post form to your @user model with accepting_nesting_attributes for account too.